# Magento 2 algolia search bar taking some time to show when website open

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.4.6, advanced-search, algolia-search

We have implemented Algolia search on our website It is working fine but we want some enhancement in the search bar display taking time.

As I have debugged code and found Magento 2 Algolia search input is appended dynamic, causing the issue in loading after the full page is loaded.

Here is a sample HTML Code that binds the search bar to this div.

```
<div id="algoliaAutocomplete" class="block block-search algolia-search-block algolia-search-input"></div>
```

**Here is js code which is appending autocomplete.js**

```
options = {
            ...options,
            container:          algoliaConfig.autocomplete.selector,//This is the selector that is appending the attached search bar in screenshot.
            placeholder:        algoliaConfig.translations.placeholder,
            debug:              algoliaConfig.autocomplete.isDebugEnabled,
            detachedMediaQuery: 'none',
            onSubmit(data) {
                if (data.state.query && data.state.query !== null && data.state.query !== "") {
                    window.location.href = algoliaConfig.resultPageUrl + `?q=${encodeURIComponent(data.state.query)}`;
                }
            },
            getSources({query}) {
              return filterMinChars(query, debounced(autocompleteConfig));
            },
            shouldPanelOpen({ state }) {
                return state.query.length >= MIN_SEARCH_LENGTH_CHARS;
            }
        };
```

[image]

My main concern the search input should loaded with all content and should not append with js. and should work as expected.